# EF:“A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column” with Id change

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I happened with this error as title said.I search the google and can not find answer,because if i use sql to insert ,it is ok,and when I use the ef to add ,it can not work.looks at below,it is my database schema.
[image]

when I try to Add something to good table ,the error occured.the fluent api of good seems that like this:

```
using ppdai.user.vip.model;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration;

namespace ppdai.user.vip.model.mapping
{
public class GoodsMapping: EntityTypeConfiguration<Goods>
{
    public GoodsMapping()
    {
        this.Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);


        this.Property(x => x.GoodsQuantity).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.GoodPrice).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.GoodScore).IsRequired();
        this.Property(x => x.GoodTypeId).IsRequired();

        this.HasRequired(x => x.GoodType)
            .WithMany(x => x.Goods)
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.GoodTypeId);


    }

}
 }
```

as a result ,good is the position of "center" table in my database ,anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: You defined foregin key by `.HasForeignKey(x => x.GoodTypeId);`

Comment: @AliSoltani it is none business with you mentioned ,because i dorp the foreign key and it still can not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like one of your foreign key columns is set to be Database Generated.
Check that `GoodTypeId` in `Goods` is not set as auto incremented Identity.
Also check the same for `GoodId` in `OrderItems` and `GoodId` in `HomePageProducts`.

Comment: nope,all foregin key is not identity,it is not related to foregin key i thought,becasue i canceled the foregin key of goods table and it still trigger the same exception. If I set the Id with not identity attribute,it will said "can not insert because the set identity_insert is off status"

Comment: The error you reported is not related to primary key, it is related to foreign key. Also, you don't have to explicitly set the primary Key to be DatabaseGenerated. By convention, the key would be automatically set to be DatabaseGenerated. Check other foreign keys too, not just the ones in Goods table.

Comment: there's not foregin key was set by datebase Generated,I check it carefully,when I use sql to insert ,it can work ,why?but ef can not

Comment: I have solved it ,as you said ,it caused with the Lottery table's primary key is goodId, and goods tables's primary key is id,and there is one to one relation with lottery and good,so if i create good table the identity is off on default.so many problem will occured.